# File broken after encoding to base64 and decoding in another app

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, encoding, base64

A PDF file is being generated client-side using `jsPDF`, encoded in base64 using `btoa()`, sent to a PHP API and there it's decoded and saved as a binary file, but it isn't working and I'm getting a malformed PDF.

PHP code:

```
$destination = 'test/file.pdf';
$content = base64_decode($content);
$uploaded = file_put_contents($destination, $content);
```

If I compare both files (The pdf file downloaded directly from the frontend, which works, vs the one downloaded from the server) this is what I get:

Original PDF File fragment (I cannot disclose the full file):
[image: original one, working well]

Post encode/decode one:
[image]

What could be causing this difference? Seems to be an encoding problem?

Comment: It seems like `btoa` does not deal well with 16-bit characters, is that what's going on here? See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa

Comment: Did you ever fix this issue? Also running into this...

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment, because I need 50 rep :) Leaving an answer instead.

Make sure you are doing your POST request correctly. Instead of your PDF file, try to post another file to the server, for example an image file and try to open posted image file on the server.

Comment: In fact, I'm posting the base64 encoded string. I compared from both sides the string and it's exactly the same.

Comment: If you encode and decode your pdf on the client side, without sending the data to the server. Will you get correct pdf file as result ?

Comment: Yes, I do. Reverting the `btoa()` with `atob()` worked perfectly. So, the problem is that decoding it from PHP gives me different results. (Good idea to try that)

Comment: please check [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding). I think there is described what to do to overcome the problem you have.

Comment: Also I would encode pdf on the client, and encode the same pdf on the server. And compare encoded data,

Comment: I've been checking that doc and suggested solutions but I have the same problem. Also, it refers to a problem on which at encoding time you get a "Character Out Of Range" exception, which I'm not getting

Comment: Do you have the same issue with another file upon sending it to the server? With an image file for example, or with a zip file ?